# parsing HTML in C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

here's my sample HTML...

```
 <html>
    <table class="test" border="0" >
        <tr bgColor="#e8f4ff">
            <td width="50%" align="right">
                <b>Invoice ID:</b>
            </td>
            <td width="50%">
                <b>
                    1622579
                </b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgColor="#e8f4ff">
            <td align="right">
                <b>Code:</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>
                    20475
                </b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </html>
```

there's no ID so ican't use SelectNodes()
    How can i get the Code: 20475 using HTMLAgilitypack or regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using latest [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex), just using the document structure - this will not be very resilient to changes in the HTML - you should strongly consider adding appropriate ids (if this is your html anyway):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"test.html");

var tds = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").ToArray();
string codeValue = "";

for (int i = 1; i < tds.Length; i++)
{
    if (tds[i - 1].Element("b").InnerText == "Code:")
        codeValue = tds[i].Element("b").InnerText;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error using this doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").ToArray();

Comment: @Leary: This requires Linq - add `using System.Linq;` if you haven't yet.

Comment: I use the SelectNode instead... but I still used your condition, thanks... It's working now