# How to get value of html element from another website MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get value of an element at https://www.americasarmy.com/soldier/1309069 Neutralizations Deaths Ratio.
using the following code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
        try
{
        client.DownloadString("https://www.americasarmy.com/soldier/1309069");
}
        catch (WebException webex)
{
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(webex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
{
        ViewBag.htmlCode = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
}
}
```

if u looked at the link above then press F12 u can see all these elements but what i get when i use this code these [elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6kRo.jpg) so what i want is to get all the elements to get the value of Neutralizations Deaths Ratio.

Comment: You can use HtmlAgilityPack to [parse the html string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355834/parsing-html-in-c-sharp-asp-net) then programmatically search for the element.

Comment: Probably want to read what the function returns: `var resource = client.DownloadString`

Comment: @Jasen This is not the problem what i want is to get all the element from https://www.americasarmy.com/soldier/1309069 the code that i used does not return with all the element like i said.

Comment: @LukeHutton this will give me that [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398465/additional-information-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-404-not-found-mv)

Comment: First, you should post the code instead of an image of the code. Second, you're getting a JavaScript client-side application back which is why the html you want doesn't exist -- the app builds it in the browser.

Comment: @Ali, when I view the URL in a browser, I get a 404 not found. This isn't necessarily a problem with the code, it is the URL.

Comment: What you're looking for is a headless browser run from your code.

Comment: Not sure why your handling 404 not found anyway, why not jus handle happy path

Comment: @Jasen sorry for posting image....so u are saying that the only way to do this is by headless browser ? do u have any headless browser you can link me it.

Comment: @Jasen idk if there is a way to save the webpage like chrome right click save as webpage, complete.

Answer (score 1):

This way solved what i want to get so as Jasen said it can be solve by headless browser i used **phantomjs** and **selenium** u can find both at nuget
i used the following code:

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;

    public  void Search(string url)
{
    var driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");
    var DivValue = driver.FindElementByClassName("ClassName");
}
```

and if you want to take screenshot u can use the following code:

```
  using System.Drawing.Imaging; 

  driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```